# How do I get a specific div's data when onClick?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am generating dynamic divs in Html and populating with PHP data. Now, when I click in one of the div's button I want to call a javascript function and pass the array of that div to javascript as a parameter.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<?php foreach (get_all_locations() as $cards) : ?>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="div_container">
        <p><?php echo $cards['id']; ?></p>
        <span onclick="edit_button_request(<?php json_encode($cards); ?>)"><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></span>
        <p><?php echo $cards['name']; ?></p> 
          <div id="main_address_div">
            <div id="address_div">
              <p><?php echo $cards['streetname'] . ' ' . $cards['streetnumber'] . ' '; ?></p>
            </div>                
          </div>                  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

JS function:

```
edit_button_request(cards){
  //get the data
}
```

I tried with json_encode() but it doesn't pass anything! What should I do?!

Comment: @hamid I am not sure what you meant!?

Comment: sorry, got you wrong

Comment: `json_encode` _returns_ a value, if you want to _output_ that value, you still need an `echo` or `print` …

Comment: @CBroe when I am debugging I dont receive anything in the JS function

Comment: Of course you don’t, because the HTML you generated, looks like this: `onclick="edit_button_request()"`. You need to _echo_ the result of json_encode in that place, so that it actually gets output between the (…)

Comment: @CBroe sorry I was doing like that but I forgot to post it here. However, when I place echo there it doesn't even call the function at all.

Comment: Then _check_ what the generated HTML code looks like in that place first of all. And check what the browser console has to say as well.